# How to point a subdomain to another subdomain?

Tags: dns, cname

I want to open foo.bar.com when user write example.com or ok.example.com to the address bar of the browser. I have tried CNAME like below, but it couldn't work.

How can I do that?

> In example.com DNS settings: type: CNAME | name: ok | domain:
>   foo.bar.com | TTL: auto

Comment: when you say 'it didn't work' what didn't work? could you resolve the cname once you added it to your dns?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a CNAME it just points to the IP address associated with that DNS name's A record (foo.bar.com). So if the server where your CNAME is pointing to doesn't listen to the domain name in your case example.com it won't work.

also example.com is the one case where a CNAME does not work, for every other subdomain it does.